# Color Space Conversion: Why lab2rgb(rgb2lab(RGB)) cannot fully recovery a RGB image?

Tags: matlab, colors, color-space, lab-color-space

After do a color space conversion from RGB to LAB,
I want to recovery the original RGB image by LAB->RGB conversion.

However,
When try: `RGB --rgb2lab --> LAB -- lab2rgb --> RGB2`,
the output RGB2 is lighter than input RGB, why?

Matlab code: `imshow(lab2rgb(rgb2lab(imread('peppers.png'))))`

in detail:

```
RGB = imread('peppers.png');
LAB = rgb2lab(RGB); %convert RGB to LAB
RGB2 = lab2rgb(LAB); %try to recovery RGB
figure, 
subplot(121); imshow(RGB); 
subplot(122); imshow(RGB2);
```

Environment: Matlab R2015a

[image]

Comment: For me images are almost identical on Matlab 2015b. What does the following command give you (numerical difference): `max(abs(double(RGB(:))-255*RGB2(:)))`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I try it in matlab R2015a and    max(abs(double(RGB(:))-255*RGB2(:)))

ans =

   73.2527

Comment: I have found the mistake. The error is caused by an overwrite version of default `rgb2lab`.Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default function provided by MATLAB will not produce this error.

This error is caused by user defined function `rgb2lab` overwrite the default function.
the overwrite function which may produce that error is as following, see `GeometricContext\src\tools\misc`

```
function [L,a,b] =rgb2lab(R,G,B)
% function [L, a, b] = RGB2Lab(R, G, B)
% RGB2Lab takes matrices corresponding to Red, Green, and Blue, and 
% transforms them into CIELab.  This transform is based on ITU-R 
% Recommendation  BT.709 using the D65 white point reference.
% The error in transforming RGB -> Lab -> RGB is approximately
% 10^-5.  RGB values can be either between 0 and 1 or between 0 and 255.  
% By Mark Ruzon from C code by Yossi Rubner, 23 September 1997.
% Updated for MATLAB 5 28 January 1998.

if (nargin == 1)
  B = double(R(:,:,3));
  G = double(R(:,:,2));
  R = double(R(:,:,1));
end

if ((max(max(R)) > 1.0) | (max(max(G)) > 1.0) | (max(max(B)) > 1.0))
  R = R/255;
  G = G/255;
  B = B/255;
end

[M, N] = size(R);
s = M*N;

% Set a threshold
T = 0.008856;

RGB = [reshape(R,1,s); reshape(G,1,s); reshape(B,1,s)];

% RGB to XYZ
MAT = [0.412453 0.357580 0.180423;
       0.212671 0.715160 0.072169;
       0.019334 0.119193 0.950227];
XYZ = MAT * RGB;

X = XYZ(1,:) / 0.950456;
Y = XYZ(2,:);
Z = XYZ(3,:) / 1.088754;

XT = X > T;
YT = Y > T;
ZT = Z > T;

fX = XT .* X.^(1/3) + (~XT) .* (7.787 .* X + 16/116);

% Compute L
Y3 = Y.^(1/3); 
fY = YT .* Y3 + (~YT) .* (7.787 .* Y + 16/116);
L  = YT .* (116 * Y3 - 16.0) + (~YT) .* (903.3 * Y);

fZ = ZT .* Z.^(1/3) + (~ZT) .* (7.787 .* Z + 16/116);

% Compute a and b
a = 500 * (fX - fY);
b = 200 * (fY - fZ);

L = reshape(L, M, N);
a = reshape(a, M, N);
b = reshape(b, M, N);

if ((nargout == 1) | (nargout == 0))
  L = cat(3,L,a,b);
end
```